# MutationObserver в IE11 - получить данные до мутации

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Вопрос по функционированию `MutationObserver` в IE. Как обычно в Chrome - работает отлично, в IE какие-то причуды. Проблема в коллбэке. Первый момент - `mutations`, в Хроме при изменении содержимого узла в `mutations` содержится 1 запись где заполнены `addedNodes` и `removedNodes`, в IE - 2 записи (Эта проблема достаточно просто решается). Второй момент - в IE нет данных о предыдущем состоянии ноды - вот это проблема.

**Как получить содержимое ноды (в IE) до изменений?**

```
function callback(mutations, observer) {
  var textBefore = null;
  var textAfter = null;
  record = mutations.pop();
  textBefore = getRemovedText(record);
  textAfter = getAddedText(record);
  console.log("old=" + textBefore + " new=" + textAfter);
  if (textBefore != textAfter) {
    var classAttr = record.target.parentNode.attributes.getNamedItem("class");
    classAttr.value += " clean";
    record.target.parentNode.attributes.setNamedItem(classAttr);
    setTimeout(function() {
      classAttr.value = classAttr.value.replace(" clean", "");
      //record.target.parentNode.attributes.setNamedItem(classAttr);
    }, 1000);
  }
};
```

Установка подписки:

```
//setup observers
var targetObject = document.getElementsByClassName("observeChild");
for (var i = 0; i < targetObject.length; i++) {
  var observerObject = new MutationObserver(callback);
  var observable = targetObject.item(i);
  observerObject.observe(observable, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true,
  });
}

//helper Code; 
function getRemovedText(record) {
  return record.removedNodes.item(0) == null ? null : record.removedNodes.item(0).textContent;
};

function getAddedText(record) {
  return record.addedNodes.item(0) == null ? null : record.addedNodes.item(0).textContent;
};
```

Вспомогательный код:

```
//random data changes
setInterval(function() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("observeChild");
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (Math.random() > .5) {
      elements.item(i).innerHTML = Math.random();
    } else {
      elements.item(i).innerHTML = elements.item(i).innerHTML + ""; //fake update
    }
  }
}, 2000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bp7yad61/2/

Comment: На Edge работает такой вариант: https://jsfiddle.net/bp7yad61/4/
Попробую на IE 11 если сработает - запишу как ответ

Comment: Нет, в IE11 не работает - пустые атрибуты у removedNodes